# How do I load a canvas from an image reliabily?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load an png into a canvas. With the following code it seems to load 10% of the time and the rest I get a blank image. I'm not sure why it isn't working. I tried loading via array instead but I get a decode error

```
<img src="/myimage.png" id="myimage">

myimage.onload = function() {
    var ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(myimage, 0, 0);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see the failures you see.

```js
myimage.onload = function() {
    var ctx = mycanvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(myimage, 0, 0);
};
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" id="myimage">

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="200" height="300"></canvas>
```